# Php function scope in included file

Tags: php, function, scope

In index.php I included some function from file (for example myfunc()) and some file (myfile.php).
In file.php I'm try use this function.

Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function myFunc...

Example code:

index.php:

```
<?php
require_once "./myfunc.func.php";
require_once "./myfile.php";
```

myfunc.func.php:

```
<?php
function myfunc()
{
    echo "myfunc test";
}
```

myfile.php:

```
<?php
myfunc();
```

Comment: And the error is?

Comment: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function......

Comment: Probably not including the file `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');`

Comment: what are the paths of the files relative to each other?

Comment: Suggested read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16959576/reference-what-is-variable-scope-which-variables-are-accessible-from-where-and

Comment: thx, but Im solved this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, this example good. 
Probably a bug in my code..

Answer (score 0):

From what i see in the code of 'myfunc.func.php' you have not added the parenthesis on the 'myFunc' function

Maybe its because you copied and pasted here i dont know but all functions need to have parenthesis even if they have no parameters.

Friendly,
Damian